# getting audio to play with getdocumenttag

Tags: javascript, audio, getelementbyid, if-statement

I am trying to get an audio file to play from within an `if else` statement but I am having a lot of problems.

The current statement I have in the code is this:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'input'+i) == '1') {
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#d00';
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = ('&bull; ALERT ' + i);
        document.getElementById('error').style.color = '#d00';
        document.getElementByTag("audio");
        audio.play();
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#090';
        document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull;' + getXMLValue(xmlData, 'inputname'+i);
        document.getElementById('error').style.color = '#fff';
        document.getElementByTag("audio");
        audio.stop();
    }
}
```

and it is loaded from an audio tag at the start of the webpage:

```
<audio preload="auto">
        <source src="success.wav"></source>
        Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>
```

I dont know if it has anything to do with the timeout i have on the entire javascript section:

```
setTimeout("newAJAXCommand('status.xml', updateStatus, true)",500);
```

as the audio clip 'success.wav' is about a second long and the refresh is 500 milliseconds?

the whole page code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/MaQVndJe

Comment: either firefox or chrome, i'd ideally like to to be cross browser

Answer (score 0):

This is meaningless.

```
document.getElementByTag("audio");
audio.play();
```

Give

```
<audio id="myAudio" preload="auto">
    <source src="success.wav"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>
```

and

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
myAudio.play();
```